# Return best matches for the input query having several features in python

Tags: python, matching, fuzzy-search

I have items as follows:

```
[
    { "id":"item1", "age": 1, "color": 'fff', "rate": 3 },
    { "id":"item2", "age": 2, "color": '000', "rate": 4 },
    { "id":"item3", "age": 3, "color": 'eee', "rate": 5 },
    { "id":"item4", "color": 'bbb', "rate": 5 }
]
```

Now, I expect user to search for a desirable item: `{"age": 1, "color": '000', "rate":5}` or even `{"age": 3, "color": 'abc'}`

I would like to find the best match(es) for this query. How do I do that?
I'm not looking for an exact answer. Although, I'm interested to implement it as a backend service, so Python should be fine. I'm just not sure how to tackle the problem. Is there some sort of a matching algorithm or a fuzzy search I need to look at?

**UPDATE**: the data is big (millions of items), there are 50-100 keys for each items, but some items might not have them all. Also the user queries might not contain all keys.

Comment: What is your matching rule? Usually, it's just simple comparison of values between  the searched and the list. For age and rate, simple numeric comparison would be good, for colors, you probably need to come up with a customized comparison or search for existing color comparison algorithms. Then once you have the distances, you can just come up with a final single-value distance and then select the one(s) that is(are) closest.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, but have a look at the update please. What do you mean by simple numeric comparison? Would it be a Euclidean distance, cosine similarity, inner product? or you mean something else?

Comment: That's up to you, for this case, a simple Euclidean distance will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How large is your dataset?

For a small dataset, you could do this in O(n*m) time (n items in list, m keys in dict) by simply taking the item that has the most matches after comparing values at same keys, keeping track of number of matches.

```
search_item = {"age": 1, "color": '000', "rate": 5}
mx = -float('inf')
for item in lst:
    curr = sum(search_item[k]==item[k] for k in item)
    if curr > mx:
        match = item
        mx = curr
print(match)
```

The search criterion might not be a simple key-value matching. You get to define that!

For a very large dataset, you could instead construct a [*k*-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) from your list and cut down search time to O(log(n)) should in case you'll be reusing the list/tree to search for multiple items.

You should **convert the hex colors to numeric type** so you have an homogenous int type across dimensions and comparison is easier, as comparing ints is way simpler than fuzzy string matching.

For example, the color `ffb` is closer to `fff` than `eee`:

```
>>> int('fff', 16)
4095
>>> int('ffb', 16)
4091
>>> int('eee', 16)
3822
```

Comment: thanks, please check the update. for a large dataset you suggest something like this? http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578434-a-simple-kd-tree-example-with-custom-euclidean-dis/

Comment: @towi_parallelism Yes, that would do. But it would be easier to work with numeric types alone. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you want the element of `data` that matches best, not the best match for each key accross all the dicts.

This could get you started:

```
>>> data = [
...     { "id":"item1", "age": 1, "color": 'fff', "rate": 3 },
...     { "id":"item2", "age": 2, "color": '000', "rate": 4 },
...     { "id":"item3", "age": 3, "color": 'eee', "rate": 5 }
... ]
>>> user_input = {"age": 1, "color": 'fff', "rate":5}
>>>
>>> criterion = lambda d: len(user_input.items() & d.items())
>>> max(data, key=criterion)
{'id': 'item1', 'age': 1, 'color': 'fff', 'rate': 3}
```

The call to `max` returns the only element of `data` with two matches here.

If you want more sophisticated fuzzy matching than just counting direct hits, for example `'ffe'` being closer to `'fff'` than `'abc'` then you need to

- define a distance metric for each type of value associated with certain keys
- use these metrics to implement a more sophisticated `criterion`.

For strings, consider the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and `abs(x - y)` for numeric types.

Comment: thanks, please see the update. Shall I use a simple `abs(x-y)` or use a Euclidean distance on the whole (possibly normalized) vector?

Comment: @towi_parallelism That's up to you. You can experiment what gives the better hits.